# How to write the grouping and replacement rule in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace 3 whitte blanks with 2 ,that is to say, to change text1 into text2.

text1

```
   test1
   test2
      test3
```

text2

```
  test1
  test2
      test3
```

My meaning is :the first group is three white blanks ,it will be matched and replaced with two white blanks;the second group kept unchanged.

It is maybe the form of `%s///g`.

1.What is the right regular expression?

```
%s/^\(\s\{3\}\)\w\+/\1  /g
```

2.why `\s\{2\}`  or `\s\{2}` can't stand for two white blanks?

Comment: `\s{2}` not `\s\{2}`

Comment: Try this : `/( {3})/g`

Comment: I think you need `%s/^\s\{3}\(\w\+\)/  \1/g` (there must be 2 spaces before `\1`). Or `%s/^\s\{3}\(\w\+\)\@=/  /g` (replace with  2 spaces). `\s\{2}` actually matches 2 whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use

```
%s/^\s\{3}\(\w\+\)/  \1/g
```

Or using a "lookahead":

```
%s/^\s\{3}\(\w\+\)\@=/  /g
```

Note that `\s\{2}` actually matches 2 whitespaces if used in the regex pattern part. It cannot be used in the *replacement* pattern (the one before `/g`), because it expected literals and backreferences (like `\1`).

Also, it is not necessary to escape the closing `}` in the limiting quantifier `\{3}` because Vim is clever enough to understand that `}` belongs to the quantifier construct, and is not a literal `}`.

**UPDATE**: If you want to match spaces up to any non-whitespace character on a line, use `\S` shorthand character class rather than `\w` that won't match `.` or `,`:

```
%s/^\s\{3}\(\S\+\)/  \1/g
```

Comment: %s/^\(\s\{3}\)\(\S\+\)/  \2/g

Comment: It is right regular expression for my meaning here.

Comment: You do not have to capture the spaces at the beginning of the line, it is redundant overhead. `\S` matches any non-whitespace, `\w` matches letters, digits and an underscore. Do you have lines starting with 3 spaces and say, a comma and you want to replace the spaces on such lines?

Comment: My meaning is :the first group is three white blanks ,it was replaced with two white blanks;the second group kept  unchanged.

Comment: I understand, but your requirements are not clear. Please add them to the question. I will update the answer. If you want to replace the spaces, do not capture them, it makes no sense.

Comment: In this context, %s/^\s\{3}\(\w\+\)/  \1/g  ==  %s/^(\s\{3})(\S\+)/ \2/g  ,i like %s/^(\s\{3})(\S\+)/ \2/g most because i got it according to your expression.

Comment: The whole point of capturing groups is that you can access their values and use them later. If you are not using the value, why capture? You only add overhead to the engine. You only need one capture group here.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't comment. I would prefer the negative lookahead here:

```
%s/^ \{3\} \@!/  /g
```

I am also not sure, if you want to match only whitespace or any kind of white blanks.

```
%s/^\s\{3\} \@!/  /g
```